Small review of topology: did I get this well?
I apologize in advance for this question, but the aim for this is to understand if I got those things well, and ask you few questions about.
Let's consider the set $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$. I can give a topology on $X$ (that has to satisfy certain properties of course), for example I choose
$$\tau = \{X, \emptyset, \{2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 5\}, \{1, 2, 3\}, \{1, 2, 3, 5\}\}$$
Now if I understood well, by definition we call OPEN all the subsets of $\tau$. In this sense $\{2\}$ is open as well as $\{1, 3\}$, and their complements are closed. This shows that $X$ is both open and closed with respect to $X$ itself.

But if we say $X \subset \mathbb{N}$, then we lose the fact that $X$ is both open and closed in $\mathbb{N}$ right?

Now, can I invent any kind of topology for $X$? Clearly it has to respect the three properties of a topology.

What are the benefits to, say, have $\tau$ as above or another topology (different from $\{ X, \emptyset \}$)? say $\tau_2 = \{X, \emptyset, \{2\}\}$?


Now, stepping into $\mathbb{R}$: I understand the standard topology is that of $T = \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, (a, b)\} \forall a, b \in\mathbb{R}$ where $a, b$ can also be infinite. In this way, I understand why any set of the form $(a, b)$ is open, like $(4, \infty)$ and so on, and why $[3, +\infty)$ for example is closed.

What are the benefits here to equip $\mathbb{R}$ with a different topology, like $T_2 = \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, \{3\} \}$, for example? Or $T_3 = \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, (0, 4)\}$?

Can I define a topology as above but with $[0, 4]$ instead of $(0, 4)$?


Thank you for answering me...
Also I hope you understand the need to ask all of this in one single question. It would be useless to separate in $N$ questions.

The sentence "Now if I understood well, by definition we call OPEN all the subsets of $\tau.$" should be along the lines of "Now if I understood well, by definition we call OPEN all (and only) the elements of $\tau.$". Subsets of $\tau$ are things like an open covering for a subset of $X,$ a basis for $\tau,$ a subbasis for $\tau,$ etc.

I'll just give my thoughts on your various points.
I agree that $\{2\}$ is open in $X$, or more properly $(X;\tau)$, and yes their complements are closed. $X$ is clopen within $X$, yes - this is true for any space.
The $X\subset\Bbb N$ comment doesn't really make sense though. To ask whether or not $X$ is open, closed or both in $\Bbb N$ makes no sense unless we impose a topology on $\Bbb N$; you would also want to put a topology on $\Bbb N$ such that $X$ is a subspace of $\Bbb N$; there will be many examples where $X$ is not open and where $X$ is open, etc. - the question is ill-posed.
I don't know what you mean by "invent any kind of topology": yes, as long as $\tau$ satisfies the three standard axioms (which can be reduced to two) of a topology, $(X;\tau)$ is a valid topological space. As for benefits, well that's kind of subtle and it really depends on what kind of problems you're trying to solve. Many sets have canonical topologies on them, and it would usually not make sense to use different ones; for example, you don't do complex analysis by viewing $\Bbb C$ as a space under the cofinite topology. But if you're doing algebraic geometry, then $\Bbb A^1_{\Bbb C}$ as a classical variety does pick up the cofinite topology - so it depends on what you're doing. If you do functional analysis, then suddenly all sorts of words come up, like "strong, weak, weak-$\ast$" in reference to various topologies on the same kinds of thing - they each have their "benefits" in the sense that studying them is useful.
You've misstated what the standard topology on $\Bbb R$ is. It has a basis of what you said, but what you wrote doesn't include the open set $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$, for example. More properly: $$\mathcal{T}_{\text{Euclidean}}(\Bbb R)=\{U\subseteq\Bbb R:\forall x\in U\,\,\exists\delta>0\,\,(x-\delta,x+\delta)\subseteq U\}$$
And finally, while $\{\Bbb R,\emptyset,\{3\}\}$, $\{\Bbb R,\emptyset,(0,4)\}$, $\{\Bbb R,\emptyset,[0,4]\}$ are all topologies, I'd dare to say none of them are useful or interesting (except, maybe, for giving counterexamples to general claims in topology). About "benefits" again - if you're looking at a problem which isn't a priori topological and you're trying to find a suitable topology to give the objects you're studying, what the "right" choices of topology are will be heavily context-dependent. It may even be a research-level question, trying to find the "answer". You'd want to ask questions like, "is it meaningful to say something is open? Compact? Are the continuous functions interesting?" and so on. Without a specific context the question doesn't really make sense, in my view.

Thank you so much for this answer. Just a curiosity, to test if I got it well so far. Suppose we equip $\mathbb{R}$ with the "stupid topology" $\tau = {\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, { 3 } } $. Now, can this be taught as a "stupid example" to show that in this case only ${3}$ is an open set? But with this topology, would it be correct to say that $(1, 3)$ or $(10, 12)$ are closed set? Here I get lost...

@Heidegger So $(1,3)$ etc. would not be a closed set in this case. It’s very important to remember that closed and open are not exact opposites and also that not every set is open or closed. In the stupid topology, $(1,3)$ is neither closed nor open. The only nontrivial closed set here would be $(-\infty,3)\cup(3,\infty)$, the complement of ${3}$. In the usual topology on $\Bbb R$ $(1,3)$ is open of course but for example $[0,1)$ isn’t open or closed. Not every set is related to the topology

I could have thought a bit more and get the answer by myself... I hate when I don't think enough and the answer is really thereby. Thank you again!!

@Heidegger You're welcome! I hate that too, but we all do it. So many times I've figured out an answer to my question just after asking it

For your first bullet point, when you ask whether $X\subset \mathbb{N}$ is open or closed, you need to decide what the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is -- once you know what the topology on $\mathbb{N}$ is, you can decide whether it is open or closed. Also, with one topological space sitting inside another, you often endow the lower one with the subspace topology, that is, $Y\subset X$ is open if $Y=X\cap U$ for some open set $U$ of the bigger space.
For your second and third bullet points, any collection of subsets of $X$ which satisfy the axioms of a topological space is a topology, so you can invent and use any topology you like. However, a topological space is not always useful in its own right -- one would prefer one topological space over another if it arises in a way which makes it useful to prove theorems for you.
The standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is exceptionally useful, as anyone who has studied analysis will tell you. You may, of course, consider $\mathbb{R}$ with lots of other topologies, such as the discrete topology where every subset is open. But, unless you have a reason to consider those topologies, you may not find them useful in proving things for you.
For your last bullet point, check out this answer about making closed intervals into a topology for $\mathbb{R}$.
Ultimately, it can seem like all the different topologies floating around are a confusing mess. However, in practice, it's a little bit backwards to start with all the topologies on a set and sort through them until you find the useful ones -- often because you are interested in infinite sets and there are going to be way too many topologies to consider. In my experience, it's more that you start with a problem, find some subsets of a set that interest you or help you solve the problem, and then prove that these subsets form a topology in order to understand them better.
In my area of study, the prime ideals of a commutative ring form a topological space called the spectrum of that ring. The spectrum is not generally useful because it teaches us about topology (although, they are very interesting topological spaces because they act very differently than $\mathbb{R}$), but because understanding collections of primes as closed sets helps us understand containments among the prime ideals, which is exceptionally important in this area of research.
